# Android Canvas Stops drawing on screen randomly

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-canvas, ondraw

I am stuck in a issue that the canvas stops drawing on screen randomly if we keep on restarting the application.

I have checked through the loggers that the method `onDraw()` is being called on action down. but my finger trace on device is not visible.

any help and suggestions appreciated.
cheers

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code in drawing on screen line or more ......

package com.kk.demo;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ZoomDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
     ImageView imageView;
      Bitmap bitmap;
      Canvas canvas;
      Paint paint;

      float downx = 0,downy = 0,upx = 0,upy = 0;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
        float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
      }

      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          downx = event.getX();
          downy = event.getY();
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          upx = event.getX();
          upy = event.getY();
          canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
          imageView.invalidate();
          downx = upx;
          downy = upy;
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          upx = event.getX();
          upy = event.getY();
          canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
          imageView.invalidate();
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what my code is, and everything is working fine except some random times when touch is not visible however debugger everytime takes me inside ontouch.